# Acceder a la camara

Tags: html5, cámara, navegador-web

se me solicito solucionar un problema el cual no lo he logrado y es por eso que acudo a la comunidad. En un portal de un cliente necesitan sacar una imagen tanto del navegador escritorio como del navegador movil. Utilice la etiqueta

```
<input type="file" class="upload" accept="image/*" capture>
```

Sin embargo esto no funciona en los navegadores de escritorio. Solo se abre la instancia de seleccionar una imagen desde el computador.

Lo he probado en Google Chrome, Internet Explorer, Mozilla y Safari sin ningun resultado. Pero si, en los telefonos. Tanto ios con safari y chrome y android con chrome funciona perfectamente.

Hice pruebas con algunos tutoriales, con diferentes etiquetas pero tambien sin resultado.

Comment: el asunto es que eso trabaja bajo el protocolo https? ahora que estuve leyendo la información en Google developers, mi codigo funciona bien, no deberia abrir la camara bajo ningun motivo.

Comment: Disculpa, esa API esta deprecada, la nueva es esta [`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)

Comment: Si, tal cual, solo funciona en `HTTPS`, mas [info aquí](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins)

Comment: hay un tutorial de david walsh el muestra y pone un ejemplo en el siguiente enlace espero te sirva saludos
[camaraweb](https://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al estar trabajando con una aplicación hecha en Ionic y con AngularJs se le planteo al cliente que la mejor opcion, para lo que el necesitaba es que fuera una aplicación movil y no web. Todo este consejo bajo obviamente el contexto al cual el cliente queria dar uso.

Gracias a todos